# Why is my memory used gradually increasing?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, memory

Getting a bit lost in the world of `top` and `free -m`, and I wondered if anyone could shed some light on what I'm seeing.

We have a PHP app build with Laravel. Recently, we've added some queues and a handler to process items on that queue. To do this, we've installed `supervisord` and we're running `queue:listen`, a command built into Laravel that basically runs a PHP script infinitely to process items.

**Note:** I'm well aware PHP is not the best solution for this. Time contraints, existing technologies, etc, all reasons why we chose to go down this route.

I deployed this to our staging server yesterday, and when I logged on today, our monitoring was alerting that the "used memory" on the box was now above 90% (it was ~20% yesterday before install). I know from past experience that this isn't a bad thing. The used memory could just be cache and/or buffers, but after logging on to the box I started to suspect it wasn't. `htop` for example was stating that most of the memory was "used" (green bars).

Getting a bit stuck, I rebooted the box. When it came back up and everything was running, it had ~15% used memory. After an hour, this was up to 25%. Looking in `htop` again, I saw this was used, not cached.

I then went onto one of our production boxes that didn't have the latest changes on to compare, and that box had the same % of cached, but far less used, matching what I'm seeing on staging. And it's had about 15% used memory for as long as it's been running.

I then stopped the PHP process by also stopping `supervisord`, and the used memory dropped ever so slightly, but not by much. This is probably just caching taking it I assume?

I'm fully aware I'm probably misunderstanding something here, but it's given me cause for concern. I don't want to run this process if something is eating and/or leaking memory to the point the system will start paging. I just want to understand *why* our memory usage is slowly increasing so I know it's not something to worry about, or is so I can fix it.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Interestingly, we're actually seeing this on 2 identical AWS boxes, one that is a test server and the other is staging. As it happens, I rebooted both at the same time, but one (staging) had the process stopped for 30 mins, while it's run non-stop on the other.

This is the difference between the two in htop,

Staging (process running for 30 mins less than Test):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                         
 5763 webapp    20   0  538m  37m  12m S  0.0  1.8   0:00.23 php                                                                              
 5497 webapp    20   0  448m  29m  10m S  0.0  1.5   0:00.61 php
```

Test:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                        
 4771 webapp    20   0  690m  47m  31m S  0.0  2.4   0:00.31 php                                                                            
 4660 webapp    20   0  603m  39m  27m S  0.0  2.0   0:00.36 php
```

In both lists, the second/bottom `php` process is the long running one started by `supervisord`. The first/top one is one that is created by the second, and is run for 30 seconds before being terminated. Essentially Laravel's queuing system polls the queues (?!).

What's interesting to see is all the MEM figures are higher on the test box, but what I find strange is the child's `php` process MEM figures are also higher. As this is started and stopped every 30 seconds, I would have expected that to be the same on both boxes. Unless it's actually a fork from the main process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Diego Velez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540883/diego-velez)'s answer, I managed to figure out what this was.

`supervisord` and `php` were doing nothing wrong, regardless of any numbers quoted to the contrary. Turns out the reason I couldn't find out where the memory was going is because it was owned by the kernal as slab allocation.

Thankfully though it's all `SReclaimable`. Ironically if I'd not checked the server today and started debugging, I'd have seen the memory usage increase and then steady out as it got reallocated around the 90% mark.

Turns out the reason the slab allocation was `dentry` cache caused by a bug in libcurl. [This article](https://www.splyt.com/blog/2014-05-16-optimizing-aws-nss-softoken) ultimately led me to the solution.

Comment: The article link now goes to a 404 page

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to install memmon, it is a monitoring tool, very handy though and lightweight. you can install it whith this command

**wget http://proj.ri.mu/installmemmon.sh -q -O - | bash && touch /var/log/memmon.txt && chmod 666 /var/log/memmon.txt**

this is just a script that is being executed every 5 minutes and the log goes to /var/log/memmon.txt, from there you can see which process is taking more memmory.

You can also use Vmstat

**vmstat -s -S M**

this command prints in a more detailed way the memory free and used, You can add this command to the memmon script using this

**echo "vmstat -s -S M" >> /usr/local/bin/memmon.sh**

to test memmon what you can do is this

**/usr/local/bin/memmon.sh >> /var/log/memmon.txt**